# My java client doesn't work with my python server

Tags: java, python, sockets, server, buffer

I am building a java client and a python server, they both work fine when I run them with their a matching language clients/server, but when I run the java client with the python server the sockets connect but the java terminal gets stuck whenever I try to read the data sent from the python server

It's likely a buffering problem, because whenever I call the buffer with the data received from python the terminal just gets stuck in said line and won't budge.

Here's the python server:

```
import socket
import pyautogui
def main():
    HOST = ""              # Endereco IP do Servidor
    PORT = 1234            # Porta que o Servidor esta
    tcp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    orig = (HOST, PORT)
    tcp.bind(orig)
    tcp.listen(1)
    while True:
        con, cliente = tcp.accept()
        print ('Concetado por', cliente)
        cone="Conectado".encode()
        con.send(cone)
        while True:
            msg = con.recv(1024).decode()
            if msg[0]=="/" :
                cmsg=''
                for i in range(1,len(msg)):
                    cmsg+=msg[i]
                exec(cmsg)
            if not msg: break
            print (cliente, msg)
        print ("Finalizando conexao do cliente", cliente)
        con.close()
main()
```

Here's the Java:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Socket soc = new Socket("localhost", 1234);
            DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(soc.getOutputStream());
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(dout);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
            InputStream is = soc.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            System.out.println("Here");
            System.out.println(br.readLine());
            System.out.println("Here2");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            while (!(bw.readLine().equals("exit"))) {
                System.out.println(br.readLine());
                String input = scanner.nextLine();
                bw.write(input);
                bw.flush();
            }
            dout.close();
            soc.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In Java, `BufferedReader.readLine()` reads a *line* meaning something that ends with a newline.  Does `con.send` send one?

Comment: @markspace: I was wondering the same thing. On the other side of things, `BufferedWriter#write(...)` surely doesn't, and for this reason, I usually use a PrintWriter or PrintStream.

Comment: Thank you, guys. Your comments were really insightful. Sorry for not answering them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I actually found out what was wrong, the problem was with the buffer it apparently didn't understand that the line was over, so to solve it I just had to send `"Conectado\n'`